# Magento Commerce Cloud 2.3 download link PDF document

Tags: magento2.3, pdf

I need to provide a download link in my footer where customers get the revocation form.

I have the following in my `phtml file`but it is not working. The PDF document is in pub/media/pdf/Muster-Widerrufsformular.pdf

```
<li class="nav item"><a href="<?php echo $this->getMediaUrl('pdf/Muster-Widerrufsformular.pdf');?>"><?php echo __('Revocation Form') ?></a></li>
```

I also tried

```
<a href="{{media url="pdf/Muster-Widerrufsformular.pdf"}}" target="_blank"></a>
```

can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can get media URL by **objectManager** method directly in your **phtml** file.

```
    <?php 
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $mediaUrl = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')
                        ->getStore()
                        ->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
    ?>

<li class="nav item"><a href="<?php echo $mediaUrl.'pdf/Muster-Widerrufsformular.pdf';?>"><?php echo __('Revocation Form') ?></a></li>
```

or you can Get By **Dependency Injection** method

```
protected $_storeManager;

public function __construct( 
    ...
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    ...
}

public function getMediaUrl()
{
    $mediaUrl = $this->_storeManager
                     ->getStore()
                     ->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
    return $mediaUrl;
}
```

and then you can call this method in **phtml** file like the below way.

```
<li class="nav item"><a href="<?php echo $block->getMediaUrl().'pdf/Muster-Widerrufsformular.pdf';?>"><?php echo __('Revocation Form') ?></a></li>
```

Comment: It is unfortunately not working, it causes a 404. The generated URL is media/pdf/Muster-Widerrufsformular.pdf, the file path is: pub/media/pdf/Muster-Widerrufsformular.pdf

Comment: Have you used the object manager method from my answer?